# Android : java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate

Tags: android, spring, resttemplate

I have getting java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate error when i run my application in my samsung mobile ,but no problem when i run the same application in other mobiles.Why its so? And i found this happens when the system executes the below line on runtime.

```
RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
```

How can I solve this? Below is my gradle build configurations.

build.gradle :

```
        apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

    android {
        compileSdkVersion 23
        buildToolsVersion '23.0.2'
        useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'

        defaultConfig {
            applicationId "com.example.myproject"
            minSdkVersion 15
            targetSdkVersion 23
            versionCode 1
            versionName "1.0"
            vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
            multiDexEnabled true
        }

        compileOptions {
            sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_6
            targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_6
        }

        buildTypes {
            release {
                minifyEnabled false
                proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            }
            debug {
                debuggable true
            }
        }

        dexOptions {
            javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
        }

        packagingOptions {
            exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES.txt'
            exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
            exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
            exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
            exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
            exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
            exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
            exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
            exclude 'META-INF/dependencies.txt'
            exclude 'META-INF/LGPL2.1'
        }
    }

    dependencies {
        compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
        compile 'com.android.support:design:23.2.1'
        compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.2.1'
        compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.2.1'
        compile 'com.j256.ormlite:ormlite-core:4.48'
        compile 'com.j256.ormlite:ormlite-android:4.48'
        compile 'org.springframework.android:spring-android-rest-template:1.0.1.RELEASE'
        compile('org.springframework.android:spring-android-auth:1.0.1.RELEASE') {
            exclude module: 'spring-core'
        }
        compile 'org.springframework.android:spring-android-core:1.0.1.RELEASE'
        compile 'org.apache.commons:commons-io:1.3.2'
        compile 'joda-time:joda-time:2.3'
        compile 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.7.2'
        compile 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:2.7.2'
        compile 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:2.7.2'
        compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.6.2'
        compile ('com.github.ganfra:material-spinner:1.1.1'){
            exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'appcompat-v7'
        }
        compile 'com.getbase:floatingactionbutton:1.10.1'
        compile 'com.github.clans:fab:1.6.2'
        compile 'com.toptoche.searchablespinner:searchablespinnerlibrary:1.3.1'
        compile 'com.github.PhilJay:MPAndroidChart:v3.0.1'
        compile group: 'commons-codec', name: 'commons-codec', version: '1.8'
        //compile group: 'com.itextpdf', name: 'itextpdf', version: '5.5.10'
        compile 'com.itextpdf:itextpdf:5.5.10'
        compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
        //compile group: 'net.sourceforge.jexcelapi', name: 'jxl', version: '2.6.12'
        compile 'net.sourceforge.jexcelapi:jxl:2.6.12'

    }
```

Below is the complete stack trace that i am getting.

```
        01-18 10:13:11.536    2131-2929/com.example.myproject E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
        Process: com.example.myproject, PID: 2131
        java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
                at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:300)
                at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:355)
                at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:222)
                at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
                at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
                at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
                at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
                at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
        Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate
                at com.example.myproject.services.ServerAuthenticateService.<init>(ServerAuthenticateService.java:41)
                at com.example.myproject.authentication.AccountGeneral.<clinit>(AccountGeneral.java:30)
                at com.example.myproject.view.LoginActivity$5.doInBackground(LoginActivity.java:197)
                at com.example.myproject.view.LoginActivity$5.doInBackground(LoginActivity.java:179)
                at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
                at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
                at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
                at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
                at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
                at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
    01-18 10:13:11.666    2131-2131/com.example.myproject I/System.out﹕ SecureActivity onResume 1
    01-18 10:13:11.666    2131-2131/com.example.myproject I/System.out﹕ SecureActivity onResume 2
    01-18 10:13:12.236    2131-2131/com.example.myproject E/WindowManager﹕ android.view.WindowLeaked: Activity com.example.myproject.view.LoginActivity has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView{41e30d48 V.E..... R......D 0,0-479,96} that was originally added here
                at android.view.ViewRootImpl.<init>(ViewRootImpl.java:468)
                at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.addView(WindowManagerGlobal.java:267)
                at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:69)
                at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:289)
                at com.example.myproject.view.LoginActivity$5.onPreExecute(LoginActivity.java:184)
                at android.os.AsyncTask.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.java:587)
                at android.os.AsyncTask.execute(AsyncTask.java:535)
                at com.example.myproject.view.LoginActivity.submit(LoginActivity.java:288)
                at com.example.myproject.view.LoginActivity$1.onClick(LoginActivity.java:111)
                at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4640)
                at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19431)
                at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
                at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146)
                at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5598)
                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1283)
                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1099)
                at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: `compile 'org.springframework.android:spring-android-rest-template:2.0.0.M1'`

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya Does i need to change the spring-android-core version to the same??

Comment: you can use same version

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya But when i sync i am getting 'Failed to resolve: org.springframework.android:spring-android-rest-template:2.‌​0.0.M1' as error

Comment: add `compile 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.4.1.3'`

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya Still getting the same exception.

Comment: I am using version `2.0.0.M3` now, with no issue. Try upgrading that.